# Get list of processes VS2012 SDK C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sdk, windows-phone-8

I'd like to create a Process Manager in my Windows Phone with my own features. Can any one help me to get the list of active process in my phone, if its possible.
I'm using VS2012 c#

Comment: Nevermind my previous answer (I've deleted it). The `Process` class is not available in the .NET API for Windows Phone, God knows why.

Comment: Windows phone is severely limited in this area. I highly doubt you'd be able to make anything remotely useful without access to first party APIs. In fact, I'd doubt you could even list the running processes, let alone do anything with them.